# Having a hard time installing Quandl

Tags: python, quandl

I have been trying to install Quandl and have been running into some issues. I used the Command Prompt and entered in my Python Path but it seems like the Command prompt just reads the input and proceeds to skip a line and does not install Quandl.

Please advise. Beyond that too, I am having a hard time getting my Anaconda to run. I think I might have messed up the installation process. I am using Enthought Canopy but my preference is more geared towards Anaconda. Is there a way to completely wipe out Anaconda from the computer and start clean?

Comment: Please share what you've tried and what errors you got (if any) so that people can help you more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a VirtualEnv for your Python project.  This will allow you to define your package library requirements in a `requirements.txt` file.

You would add the word `quandl` in this file, then activate the VirtualEnv and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.  At this point you should be able to have the library available to the VirtualEnv.

Comment: I have no clue how to do that. Would you mind going into detail?